# How to display results by creating variables?

Tags: php, casting, concatenation

I am new to PHP so please excuse my mess.  This is a very complicated query for somebody like me to change.

Please see the query below.  Right now all results are being displayed in the $row['Post']; Instead I want to be able to do something like:

$somerow = $row['some_row'];
$somerow2 = $row['some_row2'];

and then be able to use it anywhere with the $variables used above.

I tried using this below but it didn't work:

```
if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$postid = htmlspecialchars($row['post_id']);
$postname = htmlspecialchars($row['post_name']);


print("$postname and the id is $postid");
}

}
```

How can i achieve this?

Full Query:

```
$denied = "Denied";
$userid = Drawn from db for user viewing;

$sql = "SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where 
User_id = tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_1  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS 
CHAR(10)) ) AS Post FROM client_visits tv where User_id in (select contact_id 
from contacts where User_id = '$userid' ) and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_2  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM client_notes tv where User_id in (select contact_id from 
contacts where User_id = '$userid' ) and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_3  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM client_media tv where User_id in (select contact_id 
from contacts where User_id = '$userid' ) and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_4  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM client_stats tv where User_id in (select contact_id from 
contacts where User_id = '$userid' ) and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_5 ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM client_current_list  tv
where User_id in (select contact_id from contacts where User_id = '$userid' )
and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_6 ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM client_past  tv
where User_id in (select contact_id from contacts where User_id = '$userid' )
and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_7  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM  client_listers  tv
where User_id in (select contact_id from contacts where User_id = '$userid' )
and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_8  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM    client_events  tv
where User_id in (select contact_id from contacts where User_id = '$userid' )
and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_9  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM    client_admissions  tv
where User_id in (select contact_id from contacts where User_id = '$userid' )
and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'
union
SELECT  concat(  (select client_name from user_accounts where User_id 
= tv.User_id), ' commanded ' , title_10  ,' on ', CAST(other_date AS CHAR(10)) )
AS Post FROM    client_immu  tv
where User_id in (select contact_id from contacts where User_id = '$userid' )
and user_allowed = '$denied'
or User_id in (select User_id from contacts where contact_id = '$userid')
and user_allowed = '$denied'";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result == "")
{
echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

print($row['Post']);
}
}
```

Comment: Learn to use loops to avoid duplication. Your select query is the same except for the number.

Comment: Also, as a standard SO-answer by now: watch out for [sql-injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com) and stop using mysql as it's being deprecated but change to [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store each row in an array and later on pick the rows out you want to use.

```
if($rows == 0)
{
    print("I have no rows!");
}
else
{
   $allrows = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
       $allrows[] = $row;
   }
   $row1 = $allrows[0];
   $row2 = $allrows[1];
   echo $row1['Post']; // Print out first row
   echo $row2['Post']; // Print out second row
   var_dump($allrows); // Print out all the rows and the structure of this array
}
```

If you then want to use those variables everywhere, you will need to make them global, but I would advice against using global variables for things like that or for anything in general for that matter.

Comment: Using the above query it only shows one result when there are in fact two queries that should be displayed.

Comment: You only posted 1 query in your question so where should I get the second query from?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what you mean by your statement then.  I did see you executed your query twice but you don't do anything with your first execution other than checking if it actually had a result. $query and $result hold the same value (if the database didn't change in the splitsecond between the two executions).

Comment: I replaced if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

print($row['Post']);
}
}     

with your snipppet.

Comment: If you mean, it only printed one row, that's true.  You could add `echo $row2['Post'];`, this will also print out the second row.

Comment: yes but thats not convenient because there could be hundreds of rows... right?

Comment: I know that but isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Sorry, i may have miscommunicated.  I am looking for something liek this: if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$postid = htmlspecialchars($row['post_id']);
$postname = htmlspecialchars($row['post_name']);


print("$postname and the id is $postid");
}

}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11172/discussion-between-zombaya-and-ariel)